# Pull-back of polarization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, line-bundles

Let $(X, L)$ and $(Y, M)$ be two polarized abelian varieties .

According to Birkenhake C. and Lange H. in Complex Abelian Varieties a homomorphism of polarized abelian varieties $f:(Y, M)\longrightarrow (X, L)$ is a homomorphism of complex tori $f:Y\longrightarrow X$ such that $f^{*}c_1(L) = c_1(M)$.

Question: It's true that $f^*c_1(L)=c_1(f^*L)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! This is sometime called naturality of Chern classes. You can find it in many books, for instance Complex Geometry - An Introduction | Daniel Huybrechts, or Differential forms in algebraic topology by Bott and Tu.